# Html tag select onclick call servlet

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I want to create in my jsp page a select menu .If a value is clicked a servlet is called and some parameters are passed to the servlet.How can i solve it?
I want to call CercaArticoloServlet and to pass "ricerca","tiporicerca","numero_pagina","articoli_per_pagina"

```
       <form method="post" action="CercaArticoloServlet">
            <input type="hidden" name="ricerca" value="categoria_home"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="tipoRicerca" value="<%=tmp%>"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="numero_pagina" value="1"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="articoli_per_pagina" value="3"/>

        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form action attribute should point to URL of your servlet to be bound. Example:

```
action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/servlet-url"
```

contextPath is required to work in any webapp, not only in ROOT.war

Comment: I want to create a <select> tag and if i click a value i call this servlet

Comment: Try to use <select> with onchange event handler. Event handler can initiate ajax request (for example, using jquery).